# Ubuntu 17.10: Bluetooth keeps crashing

Tags: 17.10, bluetooth, crash

I have Ubuntu 17.10 Lenovo T540p. I have connected BT headset CEL-TEC F5A. It's capable of BT 4.0 and the profile used when it crashes is HSP/HFP (terrible sound + mic).

Every now and then, the Bluetooth turns off. Then I have to turn it on and reconnect the headset. I'm not sure what's the cause. Below is what I see in `dmesg`. I don't know if the entries are before or after the event, probably after (the reconnecting).

What can I try to make the connection more stable? I have no other BT devices connected.

```
[335986.898908] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[335986.908898] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[335986.908903] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[335986.908904] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[336106.877531] usb 3-11: USB disconnect, device number 49
[336106.905830] Bluetooth: hci0 setting interface failed (19)
[336107.217708] usb 3-11: new full-speed USB device number 62 using xhci_hcd
[336107.362900] usb 3-11: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=07dc
[336107.362906] usb 3-11: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[336109.393734] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-110)
[336109.393745] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0xfc05 tx timeout
[336146.986893] usb 3-11: USB disconnect, device number 62
[336147.842503] usb 3-11: new full-speed USB device number 63 using xhci_hcd
[336147.987669] usb 3-11: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=07dc
[336147.987673] usb 3-11: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[336148.002134] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370710018002030d00
[336148.002305] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq
[336148.218158] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[336158.238466] input: 00:19:5D:25:6F:6C as /devices/virtual/input/input55
[336174.700138] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[336174.710142] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[336174.710146] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
```

Edit: It has this: Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 (2x2, 802.11ac/a/b/g/n) with Bluetooth 4.0

Comment: I haven't found anything relevant in the [bios updates](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/cz/en/products/LAPTOPS-AND-NETBOOKS/THINKPAD-T-SERIES-LAPTOPS/THINKPAD-T540P/downloads/DS038148).

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing some parameters

```
echo "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0 swcrypto=1 11n_disable=8" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Reboot

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1721271

Comment: Interesting, I wouldn't suspect wifi to interfere. Should I also try flashing the firmware? If applicable. I noticed now in the `dmsg` output that it's patching firmware - really? Is that something being done on runtime?

Comment: This is what I had there (Ubuntu default I guess ): `remove iwlwifi 
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) 
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211`